# Symfony: Format date in entity depending on localization

Tags: php, symfony, date, format, entity

I have the following entity in my Symfony 4 project

```php
class Post
{
  /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="date_string", type="string", length=11)
   */
  private $dateString;

  public funtion getDateString()
  {
    return $this->dateString;
  }
}
```

*I know, I could use \DateTime for that, but it does not matter for my case ;)*

What I want is, to convert the date string depending on the localization of the user. Therefore I created a new translation and used the key "dateFormat" to set the date format for each localization.

```yaml
messages.en.yaml

  dateFormat: "m/d/Y"

messages.de.yaml

    dateFormat: "d.m.Y"
```

My question is: What is the best practice to get the formatted date string? I have written a repository method, but I do not like this solution. When I am accessing the method, I always have to fetch the repository and its not comfortable to use it in Twig templates.

PostRepository:

```php
public function getFormattedDateString(Post $post): string
{
  $dateTime = new \DateTime($post->getDateString());
  $dateFormat = $this->translator->trans('dateFormat');

  return $dateTime->format($dateFormat);
}
```

Rather I would like to use the method directly out of the entity. Something like this:

$post->getFormattedDate();

But this won't work, because I need to inject the TranslatorInterface into the Entity. This sucks. Or is there a way to modify the result of the getDateString() method? (annotations?)

How would you solve the task? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I assume you don't want to use the `IntlDateFormatter` and want to re-invent a way to translate a date.
I would do a service `LocaleDateFormatter` than you can use when you need to translate a date to a locale formatted Date (and a twig filter to use it on twig template)

```
__construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
{
   $this->translator = $translator;
}

public function getFormattedDateString($dateString): string
{
  $dateTime = new \DateTime(dateString);
  $dateFormat = $this->translator->trans('dateFormat');

  return $dateTime->format($dateFormat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a service that would expose a function, which will take your User as a parameter. It would resolve the date string you need.

For example, you could create a `DateFormatResolverInterface`, that would implement a `resolveFormat(User $user)`. Then, create a `RequestLocaleDateFormatResolver` class that implements the interface, and resolve the format inside the `resolveFormat()` function. You can always change the way you resolve the format by creating a `new class` that `implements the interface`.

Then, use this whenever you need : `$this->get('acme.date_format_resolver')->resolveFormat($user);` OR
`$this->get(DateFormatResolverInterface::class)->resolveFormat($user);`

Hope this helps.